# Incorrect data passed with UIPickerView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I am trying to use a `UIPickerView` with data 1 to 10. On click of the `button "Extend"` I am printing the value of the selected item of the picker. Sometimes it picks the correct value but sometimes it does not. eg: If I pick 8 sometimes it prints 6. Is there something I am doing wrong logically?

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        globalVariablePicker.picked = pickerData[row]
        return pickerData[row]

    }

    struct globalVariablePicker {

        static var picked = String()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileLabel1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileLabel2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    @IBAction func Extend(_ sender: Any) {

        print(globalVariablePicker.picked)
    }

    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        ProfileLabel1.text =   DetailStudentSponsoredViewController.globalVariableProfile.StringID
        ProfileLabel2.text = DetailStudentSponsoredViewController.globalVariableProfile.StringName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `globalVariablePicker` in the method but **NOT** in `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?`

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        globalVariablePicker.picked = pickerData[row]
    }

    struct globalVariablePicker {

        static var picked = String()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

        return .lightContent
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileLabel1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileLabel2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    @IBAction func Extend(_ sender: Any) {

        print(globalVariablePicker.picked)
    }

    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self

        //Initial setup
        globalVariablePicker.picked = pickerData[0] //Newline
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        ProfileLabel1.text =   DetailStudentSponsoredViewController.globalVariableProfile.StringID
        ProfileLabel2.text = DetailStudentSponsoredViewController.globalVariableProfile.StringName
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Whenever the `UIPickerView`'s row is getting dequeued from reusable pool, the value inside it will be copied to `globalVariablePicker`. This is the reason the different value is saving in `globalVariablePicker` in `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?`.

Comment: Hi @Sateesh Thanks for the suggestion. However, can you please append the correction in my code and advice? That will really help me as I am very new to Swift. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still any doubt, please let me know

Comment: Thanks @Sateesh this is working better, however after the UIView loads the first selection of the UIPicker is blank or wrong. All consequent selections are correct.

Comment: Yes...!!! I'm wondering it was not there in question . Just kidding . Added new line _globalVariablePicker.picked = pickerData[0] //Newline_ in _viewDidLoad_.